# SQL Server Update datetimeoffset composite key

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, composite, datetimeoffset

I have 2 tables:

```
Vehicles:
Id (int,PK), 
PositionTime (datetimeoffset)
Positions:
Accuracy (int), 
VehicleId (int)
TimeLocal (datetimeoffset)(VehicleId and TimeLocal are composite PK pointing to Id and PositionTime in Vehicles)
```

I want to update all the dates to today (the time stays the same) in both tables (this means that the link between tables will update too). I tried to first update Positions then Vehicles.
But I get the error:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Positions'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Positions'.
```

The duplicate key value is (1, 2014-10-09 16:13:50.0000000 +03:00). Looking in Positions, there is only a single '1,2014-04-24 16:13:50.0000000 +03:00' value in the Positions table.
Current implementation:

```
UPDATE
[dbo].[Positions]
SET
[dbo].[Positions].TimeLocal = CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS(datepart(yyyy, @date), datepart(mm, @date), datepart(dd, @date), datepart(HH, [dbo].[Positions].TimeLocal), datepart(MI, [dbo].[Positions].TimeLocal), datepart(SS, [dbo].[Positions].TimeLocal), datepart( MILLISECOND, [dbo].[Positions].TimeLocal), CAST((FLOOR(DATEPART(TZ, [dbo].[Positions].TimeLocal)) / 60) AS VARCHAR(10)), CAST((DATEPART(TZ,[dbo].[Positions].TimeLocal)%60) AS VARCHAR(10)), 3))
FROM
[dbo].[Positions]
INNER JOIN
[dbo].[Vehicles]
ON
[dbo].[Positions].VehicleId = [dbo].[Vehicles].Id
```

Thank you!!
[Added DB relationship for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNJOi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little confused by your database schema but I assume that it is something like below (it is helpful if you can include dml and set up data in the future).

```
-- Create tables
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Vehicle](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PositionTime] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__Vehicle__3214EC070A607A7B] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(   [Id] ASC,
    [PositionTime] ASC )  ) ON [PRIMARY]   
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Position](
    [VehicleId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LocalTime] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [Accuracy] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Position] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(   [Accuracy] ASC )  ) ON [PRIMARY]  
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Position]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Position_Vehicle] FOREIGN KEY([VehicleId], [LocalTime])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Vehicle] ([Id], [PositionTime]) ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Position] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Position_Vehicle]
GO

-- Load data
INSERT INTO Vehicle VALUES(1, '2014-01-01 01:01:01.6660000 +01:00')
INSERT INTO Vehicle VALUES(2, '2014-01-02 01:01:01.6660000 +01:00')
INSERT INTO Vehicle VALUES(3, '2014-01-03 01:01:01.6660000 +01:00')
INSERT INTO Vehicle VALUES(4, '2014-01-04 01:01:01.6660000 +01:00')
INSERT INTO Vehicle VALUES(5, '2014-01-05 01:01:01.6660000 +01:00')

INSERT INTO Position VALUES(1, '2014-01-01 01:01:01.6660000 +01:00',1)
INSERT INTO Position VALUES(2, '2014-01-02 01:01:01.6660000 +01:00',2)
INSERT INTO Position VALUES(3, '2014-01-03 01:01:01.6660000 +01:00',3)
INSERT INTO Position VALUES(4, '2014-01-04 01:01:01.6660000 +01:00',4)
INSERT INTO Position VALUES(5, '2014-01-05 01:01:01.6660000 +01:00',5)
GO
```

Notice the ON UPDATE CASCADE code on the foreign key on the Position table. This allows your changes in the referenced table to be reflected in the referrer table. See above. Below I have included the update statement to modify your local time column and simplified the time generation sql.

```
-- Before update
SELECT * FROM Vehicle
SELECT * FROM Position

UPDATE  Vehicle 
SET     PositionTime = DATEADD( DAY, DATEDIFF( DAY, DATEADD( DAY, DATEDIFF( DAY, 0, PositionTime), 0), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)), PositionTime) 

-- After update
SELECT * FROM Vehicle
SELECT * FROM Position
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's true I wasn't clear enough. The relation is in the linked image: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-WyYs74In7seHNfa0tqRlZNVkk/view?usp=sharing). Your answer is really close to what I need.

Comment: How is the solution I proposed not what you are looking for? The diagram you provide shows two foreign keys from Position to Vehicle on VehiceId to Id and TimeLocal to PositionTime. I may have got the initial set up slightly inaccurate but if you apply a ON UPDATE CASCADE to the DateTimeOffset foreign key and update the data in the primary table then the data modified in the vehicle table will be cascaded down to the positions table.